# Bind CommandParameter to SelectedItem of GridView

Tags: xaml, gridview, mvvm, winrt-xaml

I work an a Windows 8 application which shows a GridView on one page. When ever the user selects an item of this grid and clicks on a button, the next page is loaded with detail information of the selected item.

I am using MVVM for this and have a DelegateCommand from Prims:

```
public DelegateCommand<Route> ShowRouteDetailsCommand { get; private set; }
```

This command is initialized inside the constructor:

```
this.ShowRouteDetailsCommand = new DelegateCommand<Route>(this.ShowRouteDetails);
```

The navigation is done by Prisms navigation service:

```
private void ShowRouteDetails(Route route)
{
    this.NavigationService.Navigate(PageNames.RouteDetails, route.Id);
}
```

The routes are shown inside a GridView:

```
                    <GridView x:Name="RouteGrid"                                  
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Routes}"
                              SelectionMode="Single">
                        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate> ...
```

The command is currently added inside the app bar (just for testing):

```
 <AppBarButton Command="{Binding ShowRouteDetailsCommand}"
                      CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedValue,
                                                 ElementName=RouteGrid, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      Icon="Forward" />
```

My problem is, that the parameter of ShowRouteDetails is allways empty. It doesn't even matter if I try GridViews SelectedValue or SelectedItem property.

I know that I could easily add a SelectedRoute property, bind the SelectedItem to it and use it in ShowRouteDetails but this seems dirty to me.

Comment: ElementName=RouteGrid, Mode=TwoWay, why it's two way?

Comment: A relecit of pure desperation after not finding any solution ;)

Comment: I propose you to make 2 changes 1-bind to selecteditem 2-ensure that grid's name is accessible from the button, put them two in stack panel just to make a test.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create a var in your viewModel and bind it to the SelectedItem of the gridView? In this way, when you run the command, you have only to read the value of that var.

```
<GridView x:Name="RouteGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Routes}"
               SelectionMode="Single" SelectedItem="{Binding myVar}">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
```

Comment: I guess it's far cleaner to give the execute method of my command every thing it needs instead of changing a member variable I just have because the binding does not work as I expect it. Or to say it in another way: Your solution is what I am doing currently but it does not meet my expectations.